# -writeToFile:automatically: (NSDictionary) not successful on some user-accounts

Tags: nsdictionary, user-accounts, writetofile

I create an NSDictionary (+dictionaryWitContentsOfFile:), change some values with -setValue:ForKey: and then, when the application terminates, write this dictionary back to a file with -writeToFile:automatically.
Everything works great until I open the same program within ***another user-account***.

Has anyone a presentiment what could cause this error?

The documentation just says that -writeToFile:automatically: returns NO when some of its values are not adequate for a plist. This is definitely not the problem here.
All I can say for now is that the program can write the file when I'm at the account I'm developing from. There is another user account on my Mac which is no admin and there -writeToFile:automatically returns NO (I see this in the Console). I made that account admin but the program still fails to save there.

Thank you for any help,

Wolfgang

PS: I think i can't give you more information which isn't redundant. If you want some more in your hands, here is the code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.plist",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],NSUserName()];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        NSLog(@"create new plist");
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DefaultAppData" ofType:@"plist"];
    }
    NSLog(@"open path:%@", path);
    myPlist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
}

-(void)changeSomething
{
    [myPlist setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]] forKey:@"aKey"];
}


-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"dict: %@",myPlist);
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.plist",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],NSUserName()];
    NSLog(@"save at path:%@ successful:%d", path, [myPlist writeToFile:path atomically:YES]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it out. The app's resources folder is not the right place to save anything, because the most Mac users do not have the right to write in the application folder.

I now use

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Preferences/com.myCompany.myApp.plist",NSHomeDirectory()];
```

instead.